# how to move the position of a character in console (java)

Tags: java

```
public class Application{

    public static void main(String[] args){
       Ladybug l = new Ladybug();
       Tree t = new Tree();
       Clover c = new Clover(10);
       System.out.print(l.lady_bug); 
       l.newPos("d");
       System.out.print(l.lady_bug); 
       l.newPos("s");
       System.out.print(l.lady_bug);
       l.newPos("a");
       System.out.print(l.lady_bug);
       l.newPos("w");
       System.out.print(l.lady_bug);
    }
}
```

so my goal here is for the v symbol to be printed on different positions on the console every time i give a different command. for example:

```
(v) <--- starting position
( v) <--- after the "d" command
(
 v) <--- after s
(
v) <--- after a
(v) <--- after w
(   v) <--- after 3 d
```

I hope this example helps a little bit. to put it simply i am trying to move the v symbol without losing its former position. hope this makes sense
it doesnt let me post the rest of the code so i hope someone can give me a general idea of how i can do that

```
public class Ladybug{

    public  String lady_bug = "v";
    int x, y;
    int clover_array[] = {0, 0};
    String[] direction = {"w", "a", "s", "d"}; //w = north, a = west, s = south, d = east

    public Ladybug(){
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    public Ladybug(int x){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = 0;
    }
    public Ladybug(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setPositionY(int y){
       this.y = y; 
    }
    public void setPositionX(int x){
       this.x = x;
    }
    public int getPositionX(){
        return this.x;
    }
    public int getPositionY(){
        return this.y;
    }
    
    public void newPos(String pos){
        switch(pos){
            case "a":
                this.x = this.x - 1;
                this.lady_bug = "v "; 
                break;
            case "s":
                this.y = this.y - 1;
                this.lady_bug = "\nv"; 
                break;
            case "d":
                this.x = this.x + 1;
                this.lady_bug = " v"; 
                break;
            case "w":
                this.y = this.y + 1;
                this.lady_bug = "v\n"; 
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Not a valid move!");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Who is not letting you post the rest of your code?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the site itself. it says that i have mostly code and should add more text to explain it. even after i added more text it displays the same error. edit: nvm i somehow did it